# Javascript related problems on all browsers on one machine, not on others?

Tags: javascript, browser, cs-cart

we have an e-commerce website developed in CS-Cart 3, it is working normally on most of our machines here, tested under a vast array of different browsers, versions, OSes....
example web page (test evenironment)
http://citydev.pipehosting.it/belgio-en-it/bruxelles/brussels-card.html

clicking on first product on the big yellow button "Acquista" (Buy it now) should open a popup, with some options that need to be filled in order to proceed to cart (date, names and so on)

however, our customers sometimes don't get the popup, but the product page instead, with options that can simply be bypassed and left blank.

example: http://citydev.pipehosting.it/brussels-card-24-ore-adulti-it.html

So far, we could reproduce the error ONLY if we disable Javascript on our FF, IE, or Chrome browsers
Tested on some customer machine, it doesn't work in ANY of their browsers...

Any idea of what could be causing the JS block or conflict???

EDIT: it looks like even Google can't get the javascript...and indexed the actual product page (robots.txt disallowed access to js and lib path where most of the JS and jQuery stuff is...i allowed it...)

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: popup blocker maybe?

Comment: we already thounght about a popup-blocker, but we coudn't find trace of them...but even diallowing popups in our browser we don't get the issue...

Comment: amphetamachine: in the server Logs I cannot find anything strange...neither in CS-Cart logs....

Comment: you should always put controls on the server side so they can't be avoided. Which os have the two machines?

Comment: actually it should be something implemented in CS-cart...it's windows Xp...

Comment: What's the JavaScript code for the event listener for the pop-up?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a configuration/security problem more than anything else, but it could very well be a JavaScript error.

1. Have you confirmed that JavaScript is turned on in the browsers on the afflicted machine?
2. On the afflicted machine, hit F12 before executing your sequence of test actions, and click the "Console" tab; do any red messages appear in that?  If so, you should bring that to the attention of your developers.  More often than not, when a script stops working, all bets on app behavior are off, particularly in Angular or jQuery (based on my experience.)

Comment: I am trying to narrow the issue...

discovered one machine where the problem occurred in IE, FF, Safari and Chrome...

It had Avast Antivirus installed, disabled/expired, but its firewall was active and set to "medium protection" (office use or something similar). Tried to lower its settimg to "Home use"  and every browser worked correctly...

So the question now is....Why the hell is Avast blocking those Javascript files and scripts????